# Xamarin Forms - Error MT2002: Failed to resolve UIKit.UIEdgeInsets

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on a `Xamarin.Forms` project and I am getting the following error after I updated my `Xamarin.Forms` version to 2.4.0.74863.

```
/Users/UserName/Official/Projects/ProjectFolder/ProjectName/iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "UIKit.UIEdgeInsets UIKit.UIView::get_SafeAreaInsets()" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065" (MT2002) (ProjectName.iOS)
```

How can I resolve this?
I have **XCode 8.2.1**, **Xamarin Studio 6.1.2.44** installed in my machine.

I tried to change the link mode to 'Don't Link' (although its not preferable) but it gives different problems.

Comment: You probably need to update Xcode as well

Comment: I thought so, but that's a lot of work for me. I have to update my OS X first to do that. So I was wondering if there is any other solution

Comment: A good lesson not to get behind on updates then ;-) there is no way around it I am afraid

Comment: SafeAreaInsets is only available in Xcode 9+/iOS 11+ and matching `Xamarin.iOS` versions.

Answer (score 1):

Besides updating `Xcode (to 9.x)` you must set the `Deployment Target` to iOS 9.0 in the `Info.plist` file.

[image]

This is because `SafeAreaInsets` is only available in iOS 9 and up (as [SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover) pointed out in the comments).

**This will however mean that your app will only work on devices that run iOS 9.0 and up.**