# Xamarin Forms - Error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'UIKit.UIEdgeInsets UIKit.UIView::get_SafeAreaInsets()'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project and i am getting the following error after i updated my Xamarin.Forms version to  2.5.0.122203.

```
/Users/UserName/Official/Projects/ProjectFolder/ProjectName/iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'UIKit.UIEdgeInsets UIKit.UIView::get_SafeAreaInsets()', referenced from the method 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer::ViewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()' in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. (MT2101)  (ProjectName.iOS)
```

How can i resolve this? I have XCode 9.2., Xamarin Studio 6.3 installed in my machine.

I tried to change the link mode to 'Don't Link' (although its not preferable) but it gives different problems.

Comment: What comes to my mind: Is the iOS project referencing the same Xamarin.Forms version? Is the Xamarin framework up to date? Have you tried switching to VS for mac?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304229/xamarin-forms-error-mt2002-failed-to-resolve-uikit-uiedgeinsets?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

in PCL project you can't use UIKit library, you can use this library only in IOS Project